# Django channel consumer sending message twice to the frontend

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to build a simple chat application using django channels using simple websocket. it is working fine but
when i'm sending message to other user it is appearing twice on both end I think consumer chat method is calling twice. i can't figure out how to solve this issue!
group send function I think doing this it is echoing back its user and sending that particular message to other user as well

**Here is the consumer**

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def fetch_messages(self, data):
        room_name = data['room_name']
        room = Room.objects.filter(room_name=room_name).first()
        sender = data['from']
        receiver = data['to']
        sender = User.objects.filter(username=sender)[0]
        receiver = User.objects.filter(username=receiver)[0]
        messages = Message.objects.fetch_last_10_messages(room.room_name,sender.id,receiver.id)
        content = {
            'command': 'messages',
            'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
        }
        self.send_message(content)

    def new_message(self, data):
        room_name = data['room_name']
        room = Room.objects.filter(room_name=room_name).first()
        sender = data['from']
        receiver = data['to']
        sender = User.objects.filter(username=sender)[0]
        receiver = User.objects.filter(username=receiver)[0]
        message = Message.objects.create(
            sender=sender,
            receiver=receiver,
            room=room,
            content=data['message'])
        content = {
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': self.message_to_json(message)
        }
        
        return self.send_chat_message(content)

    def messages_to_json(self, messages):
        result = []
        for message in messages:
            result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
        return result

    def message_to_json(self, message):
        return {
            'sender': message.sender.username,
            'content': message.content,
            'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
        }

    commands = {
        'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
        'new_message': new_message
    }

    def connect(self):
        me = self.scope['user']
        other_username = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
        other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_username)
    
        room = Room.objects.get_or_create_personal_room(me, other_user)
        self.room_name = f'personal_room_{room.id}'
        # self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        print('----You are connected',self.channel_name)
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        print(f'{self.channel_name} - received message - {data}')
        self.commands[data['command']](self, data)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    
        

    def send_chat_message(self, message):    
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat.message',
                'message': message,
            }
        )

        print('----> in send chat',message)

    def send_message(self, message):
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        print(f"{self.channel_name}------------------{message}-------------<-new message data")
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))
```

**websocket frontend**

```
<script src="{% static 'chatapp/reconnecting-websocket.js' %}"></script>
<script>
  var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
  var username = {{ username }};
  var receiver_username = {{ receiver_username }};

  var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
      'ws://' + window.location.host +
      '/ws/chat/' + receiver_username + '/');

  chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
    fetchMessages();
  }

  chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      if (data['command'] === 'messages') {
        for (let i=0; i<data['messages'].length; i++) {
          createMessage(data['messages'][i]);
        }
      } else if (data['command'] === 'new_message'){
        createMessage(data['message']);
      }
  };

  chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
      console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
  };

 // document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
  //    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
  //        document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
  //    }
  //};

  document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
      var messageInputDom = document.getElementById('chat-message-input');
      var message = messageInputDom.value;
      chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
          'command': 'new_message',
          'message': message,
          'from': username,
          'to': receiver_username,
          'room_name':roomName,
      }));

      //messageInputDom.value = '';
  };

  function fetchMessages() {
    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify(
      {
        'command': 'fetch_messages',
        'from': username,
        'to': receiver_username,
        'room_name':roomName,
      }
      
    ));
  }


 




  function createMessage(data) {
    var author = data['sender'];
    var msgListTag = document.createElement('li');
    var divTag = document.createElement('div');
    var spanTag = document.createElement('span');
    var div2Tag = document.createElement('div');
    var imgTag = document.createElement('img');

    msgListTag.className = 'clearfix';
    divTag.className = 'message-data text-right';
    spanTag.className = 'message-data-time';

    div2Tag.textContent = data.content;
    
    
    if (author === username) {

        

      imgTag.src = '/media/{{request.user|personal_profile_image }}';

      div2Tag.className = 'message other-message float-right';
    } else {
      imgTag.src = '/media/{{receiver_user|personal_profile_image }}';
      div2Tag.className = 'message my-message';
    }
    msgListTag.appendChild(divTag);
    divTag.appendChild(spanTag);
    divTag.appendChild(imgTag);

    msgListTag.appendChild(div2Tag);
    document.querySelector('#chat-log').appendChild(msgListTag);
  }

</script>
```

**here is the output on frontend**
[image: here's the image of frontend]